# How do I link a hyperlink to an HTML5 <li> image that uses data attributes

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

This is a responsive HTML5 gallery that I've been working on recently. I just want each image to link to a different page.

```
<ul class="gallery">

    <li>

    <div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Project</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350" >
    <div data-src="images/xxxlarge/1.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div>

    </div>

    </li>
```

I know that it should be as simple as adding a `<a href="#"></a>` but this isn't working. I am open to hear about other options.

Comment: `data-` attributes are just attributes. They don't add any new functionality to your page.

Comment: Of course. What would you recommend doing to link this image?

Comment: Wrap it in an anchor tag or use JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the values in data-attributes (`data-*`) using `.dataset` ([currently supported](http://caniuse.com/dataset) in all major browsers). I.e. to access the value of the attribute `data-src` of an element, you would write:

```
var srcValue = varHoldingElemNode.dataset.src;   // or
var srcValue = varHoldingElemNode.dataset["src"];
```

That said, you can use some JS to achieve what (I suppose) you want: turning a `<div data-src=<url_to_image>...` into an image linking to some page.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/c8P66/)**.

Comment: It still isn't working for me. May I please send you the JS for you to look at?

Comment: I've been wrapping and nothing still happens

Comment: Sure, posting code always helps getting more informative answers.

Comment: So there is a singleview modal window that opens up when an image is clicked. I'm trying to disable to singleview and instead link each image to a page.

Comment: I still don't see the problem :)

Comment: This page however doesn't work in IE so you'll have to use chrome or FF

Comment: @Will Jordan: This gets way out of your question's scope, but: Download **[this file named "es_gamma.js"](http://dfiles.eu/files/fwhdpjn75)** and replace your original "gamma.js" script with it. It should work as expected. If you want to see what changes I have made to the original file, search for a line containing `[ExpertSystem]`. Also note that should not mess with libraries you don't understand. Even a slight modification could break something important. (Needless to say, you use my file at your own risk blah, blah, blah...)

Comment: What if I want the link to open in the same window? Thank you so much! This is it! This is a very difficult library for me, I completely understand. You guys are so talented. I only hope to work with developers with such caliber someday.

Comment: Always glad to help (I wish I were so talented as you say - lot's of people here at SO sure are). Anyways, if you the link to open in the same page: Find that "[ExpertSystem]" line and 2-3 lines below that comment out the `target: "_blank"` part. Don't forget to always mark as "accepted" the answer that helped you solve your problem, so future visitors can easily spot the answer.